# split script google spreadsheet v2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I wish that every new response entry in my form, the line is copied to another sheet. Then, if the row consists of cells with multiple data, these cells are split across several rows, as on my sample sheet. Finally, the new entry always takes place after the last non-empty line.

Is it possible to do this?
If I am not yet precise enough, please tell me.

Cordially.

[File link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x1oycItwx_I_69lQT03CsCJKPIwdTPPoOqL0k6-wWCY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I've edited your post and removed the statement: "During my last request, I was not precise enough from where my new question."  That is personal information that is not needed in order to understand what the problem is.  Also, you should include code in your question.  The link to the spreadsheet is good, but the post should contain enough information to understand the problem without the need to visit an external source.

Comment: To put new data in the last non-empty line, you can use the `sheet.appendRow()` method.  It simple to use.  Try it.  [Apps Script documentation for appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you close to what you want. I added sheet 'Feuille 2' to hold the retutned data. You could run this from a onFormSubmit functionL

```
function splitAll(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("Réponses au formulaire 2")
 var lr=s.getLastRow()
 var range=s.getRange(2, 2, lr-1, 3).getValues()
 var output=[]
 var split=[]

 for(var i=0;i<range.length;i++){
   for(var j=0;j<range[0].length;j++){
     if(j==0){}
     if(j==1){
    var split=range[i][j].split(", ")
     if(split.length != 1) {
       for(k=0;k<split.length;k++){
         output.push([range[i][0],split[k],""]);}
     }else{
         output.push([range[i][0],range[i][j],""]);
     }}
      if(j==2 && range[i][2] !="" ){
    var split=range[i][j].split(", ")
     if(split.length != 1) {
       for(k=0;k<split.length;k++){
         output.push([range[i][0],"",split[k]]);}
     }else{
         output.push([range[i][0],"",range[i][j]]);
     }}
    }}
 ss.getSheetByName("Feuille 2").getRange(2, 1, output.length,   output[0].length).setValues(output)
 }
```

Comment: thanks @Ed Nelson for this code, I tried your code, it works except when a column is empty or when a column is added. I can not understand. I changed the column number in getRange (2,2, lr-1, 5) for example), but nothing happens. May I have a clarification please? Cordially.

Comment: I am sharing a spreadsheet with a column added and an explanation of what I changed. I hope it helps you understand the code. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MjKctjb9fuMyGuMD7uaX47R05vSEzGjmdzRfJn5VrDY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello @Ed Nelson,
I just see your code and actually the code works :)
However, I have a question about syntax.
What is the difference between these 2 syntaxes?
To line 35 : output.push([range[i][0],split[k],"",""]);
and to line 43 : output.push([range[i][0],"",split[k],""]);
I speak of the location of "".

Cordialy.

Comment: "" Is used to place the column you want split, right?

Comment: I added an explanation to the bottom of the code in the shared spreadsheet.

Comment: I had almost understood :) I will try to dissect your code, in order to better understand it in its totality. And why not find an automatic solution if I have 50 columns ^^.

Again thank you @Ed Nelson for your patience and kindness.

Cordially.

Comment: If this helps, could you please approve the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer . If you have any more question, just ask. You can put questions in the shared spreadsheet and I will look for them. Thanks.

Comment: hello, I come back to you because I do not understand one thing :( when you write "var output = [ ]" [ ] means a table?

Cordially.

Comment: No. output is an array. output.push([range[i][0],"",split[k],""]) is writing elements to the output array. If you run in debug, you will see what is happening.